# Set ClaimsAuthorizationManager in Code (MVC 5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif, claims-based-identity

I've got an ASP.NET MVC 5 app and I'm trying to get my head round Claims authorization. I've read a bunch of stuff that always sets the `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` class in the web.config file.

Is it possible to set a custom `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. In the ApplicationStart method in my global.asax file, use the following code:

```
 System.IdentityModel.Services.FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfigurationCreated += (s, e) =>
        {

            e.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.ClaimsAuthorizationManager = new MyCustomClaimsAuthorizationManager();
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this slight elaboration on the answer could help someone else out, as i just went through something quite similar in MVC 5, .NET 4.5.2, and found that it's worth understanding how these components behave under the hood.

My main goal: needed to minimize .config dependency (ffwd: in the time i had available, i found ways to minimize but not completely remove)

The issue i ran in to with this answer's approach is i kept on getting an error saying i was missing config stuff.  after some good old reflector-reflection, i found that this is caused by the mish-mosh, daisy chain of static getter, instance construction, and member initialization between the `FederatedAuthentication`, `FederationConfiguation`, and `IdentityConfigution` classes.

First, the `FederatedAuthentication` class's `FederationConfiguration` getter property lazy initializes the underlying 'FederationConfiguration' field.

```
public static FederationConfiguration FederationConfiguration
{
    get
    {
        if (_federationConfiguration == null)
        {
            object federationConfigurationLock = FederationConfigurationLock;
            lock (federationConfigurationLock)
            {
                if (_federationConfiguration == null)
                {
                    _federationConfiguration = CreateFederationConfiguration();
                }
            }
        }
        return _federationConfiguration;
    }
}
```

To summarize the initialization routine:

1. call `FederatedConfiguration` default ctor (which calls in to `: this(true)`, but i digress)
2. fire the 'FederationConfigurationCreated' event, which your code will handle and do whatever it does
3. light validation
4. if not already initialized, kick off initialization chain

   ```
   private static FederationConfiguration CreateFederationConfiguration()
   {
       System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.FederationConfiguration federationConfiguration = new System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.FederationConfiguration();
           federationConfiguration = OnFederationConfigurationCreated(federationConfiguration);
           if (federationConfiguration.IsAmbiguous)
           {
               throw DiagnosticUtil.ExceptionUtil.ThrowHelperError(new ConfigurationErrorsException(System.IdentityModel.Services.SR.GetString("ID7018")));
           }
           if (!federationConfiguration.IsInitialized)
           {
               federationConfiguration.Initialize();
           }
           return federationConfiguration;
       }
   }
   ```

Understanding this routine is important because, it's not outwardly apparent (at least to me) that if you did hook in to the event and tried doing some off-the-reservation stuff, you need to know to call either the `FederationConfig` and/or `IdentityConfig` class' `Initialize()` methods to potentially avoid some of the side effects that occur if they are otherwise called for you.

There is a pattern of "if is not initialized, call `Initialize`" that run down the chain of objects and due to the implementation the `IsInitialized` properties on these classes can only be set to return `true` if their `Initialize()` methods successfully complete.

The way I was able to set my custom `ConfigurationManager` and avoid some errors due to .config dependency was make my event handler smart enough to preemptively call the `Initialize()` method on the `IdentityConfiguration` object - this actually changes the path of execution within the framework's IdentityModel classes.

```
var authZ = new MyClaimsAuthorizationManager();            

FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfigurationCreated += (s, e) =>
{
    var identityConfiguration = e.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration;

    identityConfiguration.ClaimsAuthorizationManager = authZ;

    if (!identityConfiguration.IsInitialized)
        identityConfiguration.Initialize();
    };
}
```

There's a few blogs/SO answers that spoke to how to programmatically set this, all of which had the simple loc: `e.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.ClaimsAuthorizationManager = new MyCustomClaimsAuthorizationManager();` in the event handler; unfortunately for me, this wasn't enough due to what i was trying to accomplish.  hopefully this can help someone else where the "simple answer" wasn't enough.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to set it through the `ServiceConfiguration` class:

```
ServiceConfiguration.ClaimsAuthorizationManager = new MyClaimsAuthManager();
```

Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.configuration.serviceconfiguration.claimsauthorizationmanager.aspx

Comment: SimonC, That is for <.net 4.5. I can't seem to find the class for .net4.5+